# How to fix a Damaged APFS disk?

Tags: macos, partition, apfs, diskutil

I have an issue with a 1TB 850 Evo, serving as an external disk in a SATA enclosure. I would Really like to recover the data I have on it so any help would be greatly appreciated.
The disk has been running fine as an APFS for a long time. Suddenly it became unnreadable, possibly after using it it in a different USB enclosure. When plugged inn, the disk does not mount. I have tried the below fixes/analysis after browsing this forum. Is there anything else I can do to analyse and/or attempt a repair?

Readout from GPT and Diskutil:
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Last login: Wed Aug 14 18:10:42 on ttys000
Framelands-MacBook-Pro:~ frameland$ sudo gdisk /dev/disk4
Password:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

Partition table scan:
MBR: not present
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk4: 244139185 sectors, 931.3 GiB
Sector size (logical): 4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 59E13892-D1CC-4871-AE60-652455350D51
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 244139179
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 244139174 sectors (931.3 GiB)

Number Start (sector) End (sector) Size Code Name

Expert command (? for help): o

Disk size is 244139185 sectors (931.3 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector  End Sector  Status   Code
1             1             244139184   primary  0xEE

Expert command (? for help): q
Framelands-MacBook-Pro:~ frameland$ sudo gdisk /dev/disk3
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

Partition table scan:
MBR: protective
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk3: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2BA6A682-802B-40E9-8DCB-D924582CFC8C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2021 sectors (1010.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)  End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1       40              409639        200.0 MiB  EF00  EFI System Partition
2       411648          1953525127    931.3 GiB  AF0A

Expert command (? for help): o

Disk size is 1953525168 sectors (931.5 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector  End Sector  Status   Code
1             1             1953525167  primary  0xEE

Expert command (? for help): q
Framelands-MacBook-Pro:~ frameland$

Framelands-MacBook-Pro:~ frameland$ diskutil apfs list
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 6801A9B4-1736-46EE-BABA-0DEB9ED0D53C
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk1
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      499963170816 B (500.0 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   460495699968 B (460.5 GB) (92.1% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       39467470848 B (39.5 GB) (7.9% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 3689942A-E50C-4A74-A827-B763D501115A
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       499963170816 B (500.0 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s1 6EEB904E-B771-3E0B-8048-C3E4BB58F07A
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
|   |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         450106273792 B (450.1 GB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s2 B8CA2171-4A7A-41DB-9E34-F6AEC2EDFC9D
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
|   |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         46379008 B (46.4 MB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s3 2B5101E3-2892-466D-ADEA-8DB3D4B91B7B
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
|   |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         510283776 B (510.3 MB)
|   |   FileVault:                 No
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s4 0776BB08-4E72-478C-AD79-8B905F797AD8
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
|       Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
|       Capacity Consumed:         9671274496 B (9.7 GB)
|       FileVault:                 No
|
+-- Container ERROR -69808
    ======================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk3
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69620
    Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69620
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk2s2 CE445FE6-2BFE-416E-AF22-007E56AC0D3D
    | -----------------------------------------------------------
    | APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk2s2
    | Size:                       999994101760 B (1000.0 GB)
    |
    +-> No Volumes
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party software packages for recovering lost, damaged, or deleted files. These work to varying levels that depends on if the disk space has been written over. Disk Drill, TestDisk for Mac, and others are included in a reference given at [this link](https://7datarecovery.com/best-recovery-apps-mac/) of the best free data recovery packages in 2020. Most packages like this are not cheap so a free one is maybe the best bet.

Not included in the list are [EasyUs](https://www.easeus.com), [Stellar Data Recovery](https://www.stellarinfo.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjw19z6BRAYEiwAmo64LV-ZKAGLgf5xSJ-p5sQ_SUXeYvYUeg2IXKDLWD8tk1kg538BWOn8aBoCBlMQAvD_BwE) and [Recoverit](https://www.wondershare.net/ad/data-recovery-mac.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw19z6BRAYEiwAmo64LWc8APa8eYX9aR3GFE-BumTfderDW6hDd5Q672tjDNWDAond6nMqDBoCjn4QAvD_BwE). These are commercial packages and are not free although they may have free trial versions.

You have to decide for yourself which one sounds best. The only one I've used is the free trial version of Stellar Data Recovery. It worked ok finding some of my deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the affected disk hasn't been wiped, so that we can still work with it, let's get some more info about the disk's structures, since the output provided by `fsck_apfs` that you saw in Disk Utility isn't particularly helpful. We need to know more about the role of the malformed object with OID `0x148d6d` that is mentioned in the output.

Please [download and compile `apfs-inspect`](https://github.com/jivanpal/apfs-tools), then run it on your affected disk so that we can get a better idea of what's going on under the hood. Assuming that the output from `diskutil` is the same as that in your question, this is done with `sudo apfs-inspect /dev/disk2s2` or `sudo apfs-inspect /dev/disk3`. Share the output here using [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or similar, since it will be very long.

Comment: Thanks for the tool. By any chance would you be able to know what's wrong with the map here? https://pastebin.com/De5RVSRy

Comment: @Kwadz, you need to specify the APFS partition, not the disk it resides on. This is probably `disk2s1` or `disk2s2` in your case. Having said that, it seems that there is no partition map on your disk, so you'll need to sort that out first.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the media is formatted to Dos32.  You need to reformat the drive to exFat.

[image]

Explanation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large-file_support

Comment: I am nnot sure that I understand your comment. The disk has been working fine for a lonng time, suddenly it didn't work. I am not yet innterested in reformatting it as I have importannt data on it. I would very much like any advice on how to possibly restore it before I wipe it :)